# Is this a good use case for rel=canonical

Tags: rel-canonical

I have two pages with similar content with slightly different text for eg graduate degree vs masters degree.

Logically they are same terms but users use these two different terms to search.
If I have  a page with content around Masters degree in healthcare and another page with graduate program in healthcare, they would have around 60% similar content.

The url would be 
example.com/graduate-program
example.com/masters-program

Is this a good idea to point the page example.com/graduate-program to example.com/masters-degree

If yes,then which of the pages get indexed ?

What is the best way to handle such scenarios ?

Comment: What do you mean by 60% similar content? Please be more specific on it, Do you just changing the keyword with other? There are many of people like to rank for similar keywords, but doing such practice, they can't rank for any of keyword.

Comment: Technically these two terms are same. Colleges who offer master degree are doing with graduate programs. So content cannot be unique and will be some overlap. Think of Amazon top 25 best seller vs 25 new York times best seller. There is an overlap here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so. In this case, the most important part that differentiates both pages is the words "masters" vs "graduate".
Using canonical you are basically telling google that you prefer one over the other, but they are not exactly similar, while with a lot of similar content, they are for 2 different programs.
Since 60% is similar, I would say tweak it a little more, use different words / content and leave it alone. That would be my opinion.

Comment: I second that! It sounds like you are within the safe zone on this one. You can simply munch mangle it a bit more to be sure.

Comment: Another idea would be to have to two titles, something like plugins for wordpress ? I think I need to do an A/B testing to see how these pages fare in eyes of google.